# How to run a function passed dynamically?

Tags: vue.js

I have a dynamic table component where I pass the values by array.
But I can not call a function passed by this array.

```js
methods: {
    getLog () {
       let newLog = {
         'lead_id': `<a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="showLog(${element.integration_id})">${element.lead_id}</a>`,
         'name': element.lead_name,
         'email': element.lead_email,
         'status': status,
         'due_date': element.integration_datetime
       }
       arrayLog.push(newLog)
    },

    showLog(id){
        console.log(id)
    }
}
```

I expect on click on link with event @click runs the function showLog()

Comment: Show us how you're inserting the HTML element into the DOM.

Comment: Is `arrayLog` in your component's data object? if so you will need to call `this.arrayLog.push(newLog)`. What does ID reference in your click method, for you to show ONE entry from `this. showLog` it will have to be the index of that array.